# how can I get the method to be outside of the main method in vlab

Tags: java, vlab

This is an assignment in vlab. I know the method needs to be outside the main method but I can't seem to understand how I can do it between the two comments. You can not edit the code outside of the // your code starts here and your code ends here.
[image of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEF8z.png)

[first part of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VblQ9.png)
[last part of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tORcl.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try to return 0 or 1 as return. For example, 0 means False and 1 means True. Then write output statement inside a main method.

```
if(vals[i] == vals[i+1]){
   return 1; }
else{
   return 0; }
```

Comment: Please read [answer].  What you have posted is, at best, a comment.  You don't have enough rep to post comments yet.  Contribute in other ways and don't post comments until you have the necessary rep.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).